# Width issue with two pages

Tags: php, wordpress, css

I've having trouble understanding whats going wrong in the css on this page.

On the left sidebar there a h3 element called testimonials with a 3px green border underneath it.

http://goo.gl/L7Lio

For some reason the border goes right up to the text in the next column next to it.

However on this page which use's exactly the same css it doesn't have that problem everything is aligned in the left sidebar correctly.

http://goo.gl/oL3km

Comment: is this happening in every browser?

Comment: yes it is punit. I've tested ff and IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content DIV has 490px vs 500px (here it is the space of 10px)

Comment: I've tried changing it now I've got a small gap but the 3px border lines aren't the same size as the dotted borders like on the other page.

Comment: Your `.sub li` has a specific width of 240. Delete that width property. The width of 100% of the `li`st will be like the H3.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS class of the content is `floatright posts` and its width is `500px`. The rule is set here:

```
.single-page-testimonial .posts {
    width: 500px;
}
```

The CSS class of the content of the correct page is `post floatright sidebar-exist` (with the additional `sidebar-exist` class) and its width is `490px`. The rule is here:

```
.single-page-no .post.sidebar-exist {
    width: 490px;
}
```

So your main content is wider than the correct one 10px. I think you may miss the class `sidebar-exist` somewhere.

Comment: I've changed this its improved it a little but, but the border is still longer then the other images/dotted backgrounds.

Comment: its like there is a 10px gap created somewhere

Comment: Check the rule `.sub li`, Your `li`s inside the sidebar have been set to 240px width, narrower than the sidebar itself 10px.

Answer (score -1):

`.post h1, .mid-title {
            border-bottom: 3px solid #004732;
            color: #004732;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 30px;
            margin: 10px 0;
            padding: 0;
           }` this css style is overwriting your h3 style,dude to which your facing that problem.

Solution:
just replace `margin: 10px 0;` with  `margin: 10px;`. this will solve the problem, i`ve checked in firebug :)

Happy coding :)

Comment: If I look at both pages they both have that same margin, so I'm afraid this doesn't solve my issue :(

Comment: You could overwrite the margin only for this h3 tag by giving it a element level css `<h3 class="mid-title" style="margin:10px;" >Testimonials</h3> `

Comment: if I do this then it comes in to much on the left, looks like its been indented. I'm using inspect element in chrome btw.

Comment: There can also be elements with `width:100%` so it's not OK to add `margin:10px` for each.

Comment: oh, I verified on Firefox, it was perfect :)

Comment: Any more suggestings would be great

Comment: I need to make sure its all flush up with the rest of the sidebar